# Committed use discounts don't match documentation

Tags: google-compute-engine

According to this page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing the monthly price for an e2-medium in us-west1 for three years is $11.01.

However, when I go to purchase commitments, and select "General-purpose E2" and two vCPUs and 4GB of memory, for three years, it tells me it would be $18.17/month. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I used the pricing calculator and also got $11.01. Other factors that affect pricing are storage and IP addresses. Your question does not include those details.

Comment: But I wasn't asking for commitment pricing on those details. I thought we just just "prepaying" on the CPU and RAM usage. The form I was filling out didn't say anything about storage or IP addresses.